# Is there a way to reuse a part of a pattern in a C++ regex?

Tags: c++, regex

I want to see if a sequence is (conditionally) surrounded by something.

Example case 1 - `cat` with the option of beeing surrounded by squared brackets.

```
[cat] // -> matches
cat   // -> matches
```

`\\[?cat\\]?` seems to be the regex solution, however that also undesirably matches for `[cat` and `cat]`!

I could use `cat|\\[cat\\]` to treat both cases individually. But I just had to write the expression `cat` twice.

Instead, my goal would be to somehow reflect the `?` (one or zero occourency) behaviour upon both the `\\[` and `\\]` expressions.

**So is there a way to treat two (or more) expressions as one unit and reflect upon that all within one regex?**

---

So let's say for case 2 I want to check for floating point numbers. It is a similar situation:

a `.` surrounded by at least 1 number.

```
1.5 // -> matches
.0  // -> matches
1.  // -> matches
50. // -> matches
2   // -> doesn't match
.   // -> doesn't match
```

In this case I would like to reflect the `+` (at least one occourency) behaviour upon the two digit sections. But I don't know how and the only ways I curently know to solve this just don't seem optimal:

- splitting up the regex into OR sections
- two regex runs (first checks if the expression is a single dot)
- capturing and counting match character count. (`std::smatch`)

I really don't want to do this as in my real world program my current strings are very complicated containing sub-expression that follow these patterns within the pattern itself. If there is a way to solve this with a single regex I could avoid a huge mess of code.

Comment: Use regex subroutines with `boost::regex` or simply build the regex pattern dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat a pattern in C++ when using `boost::regex`, it is possible to use [**regex subroutines**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html): capture a pattern you need to repeat and use `(?n)` where `n` is the capturing group ID. Use `(?R)` to repeat the whole pattern.

[Example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/862b042c0b89c873):

```
std::string s{"This is a cat"};
boost::smatch what;
boost::regex expr{R"~(\[(cat)\]|(?1))~"};
if (boost::regex_search(s, what, expr))
{
  std::cout << what[0] << '\n';
}
```

`std::regex` does not allow that. You need to build patterns dynamically:

```
std::string s{"This is a cat"};
std::string block{"cat"};
std::smatch what;
std::regex expr{"\\[" + block + "\\]|" + block};
if (std::regex_search(s, what, expr))
{
  std::cout << what[0] << '\n';
}
```

See [this C++ demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0f72d7430072364).

Comment: Seems promising. Thanks. It's sad that such a fundamental step towards turing completeness isn't available for `std::regex`

Answer (score 1):

Problem with regex's is they're not turing complete, so you have to hack about to get clever things like this from them.

For your:

> a `.` surrounded by at least 1 number.

first search for:

```
[0-9]*\.[0-9]*
```

raising an error for anything that doesn't match and then search for the negative:

```
[^0-9]\.[^0-9]
```

and raise an error if that matches.

Comment: well, but now `"abc"` or `"5"` would not match and therefore pass on, even though they are not floating pointer number. I would be forced to perform a second check. Then `two regex runs (first checks if the expression is a single dot)` seems to get me there in the first place.

Comment: @StackDanny That's now fixed and `"abc"` or `"5"` won't match.

Comment: The key element that allows this to work is that `\.` stays positive on both ways. So, like I said, you just look for a single `\.` in the first place and get there without having to invert things.

Comment: @StackDanny Really hard to keep track of what exactly you're asking since you keep on moving the goal posts. :(

Comment: what I need here is to reflect the + (at least one occourency) behaviour on the two digit sections. A shame that this doesn't work. I appreciate you sharing your insights on the topic, thanks!

Comment: @PaulEvans OP has clearly asked how NOT to repeat a repetitive part of a pattern in a regex. You are not addressing the issue trying to suggest an alternative pattern for a sample problem OP used as a showcase for the functionality OP seeks.

Answer (score 0):

Another try using lookaround to check the length in order to avoid unwanted matches.

```
^(?=.{2,})[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VMgKL5/3

Comment: Clever idea, sadly it only works for cases where the expression inside has a constant expected length.